# Android: Add separate resources for tests only

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am developing an android library.

The library takes in some parameters. For instance, it has a setStyle method which takes in a reference to a style resource:

```kotlin
fun setStyle(@StyleRes style: Int) ...
```

I want to test this method. To do this, I want to pass a resource `TestStyle` to the library in a unit test. Something like this:

```kotlin
myLibrary.setStyle(R.style.TestStyle)
```

However, I don't want to create the `TestStyle` resource in the main `src/main/res/values/styles.xml` because this would make the resource available to people using my library. I want it to only be available in tests.

Instead, I tried to place the `TestStyle` `<item />` in a new test-only file  at `src/test/res/values/styles.xml`. However, I can't figure out how to access this in the unit test, as it is not available through R.

How can I create resources that are only accessible in tests and not in other parts of the code?

Comment: add resource in debug flavor of your app. that will not be available to your released library. Otherwise i don't see way to achieve your requirement

Comment: @alokHarman hm, that's a good idea, I will use this as a temporary solution.

Comment: @alokHarman this will work for debug unit test, but release units tests will fail. So, if you run "gradlew test" from the command line, it will fail.

Answer (score 5):

Place your resources in some folder. For example "src/test/res". And use the following gradle configuration:

```
android {
...
  testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    android.sourceSets.main.res.srcDirs += 'src/test/res'
}
```

This way, the resources will be visible for debug and release test builds, but they will not be packaged to your library or app.